# Image picker from server (path only)

Tags: library, images, php

I'm building a page for my local association where the users will be making news items. I need them to upload an image to the server and pick that image as header. The output (title, subtitle, content and image header) are written to the DB. I'm using CKEditor in combination with CKFinder. But CKFinder always uses `<p>` and `<img>` while I only need the path. Which library/plugin can I use for this issue?